# Image Gallery Carousel Title and caption placement

Tags: sharepoint-server, image, title, carousel

The title and caption fields for each of my image gallery photos now shows directly across the image blocking the faces of the people in the images.  It used to be at the bottom.  Is there a way to revise that? [image: sample image with text]

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this issue in my SharePoint Online.

Have you added some code in the current page?

1.Delete this image gallery web part, re-add, have a test.

2.Create a new page, add the image gallery web part, compare the result.